# Installing from subversion (with --upgrade) by pip only when something (code/revision) changed

Tags: python, svn, installation, pip, upgrade

To install the latest version of the project from svn i use:

pip install svn+ssh://svn.myproject.org/svn/MyProject/trunk#egg=MyProject --upgrade

But it's being uninstalled and installed even, when nothing changed..

When it's used by CI like Jenkins many times (in loop) - it's so huge waste of time.

The question (and the problem) is to avoid that. Is it now possible? I didn't see that kind of option. That would be so great optimisation..